# Which Hadoop data type would be most appropriate for a key that represents a year - Text or IntWritable?

Tags: hadoop

In my application, I need to use year as they key. I think Text will be more appropriate for key since we usually group a certain measure by year, and IntWritable is used for values that we sum, or average. But I also think we can use IntWritable as the type for year, since we can represent year as int, there is nothing preventing it right? I would like to understand which is more appropriate for a year as key - is it Text or IntWritable?

Answer (score 2):

Both are suitable, but there is an important difference when it comes to efficiency.

Firstly if you have a 'smaller' number of records what i'm about to discuss is probably so insignificant that it's not worth worrying about. However if you plan to process TB's of data then cycles saved *could* add up to minutes.

Like Amar points out in his answer a Text will serialize the year value as a series of UTF-8 encoded characters. It actually outputs a VInt for the number of bytes, then the bytes themselves. Typically years are 4 characters in length so a year will be serialized to 5 bytes of data (1 byte length, 4 bytes content).

An IntWritable is always serialized as 4 bytes - but you can hold numbers in the range +/- 2 billion in this byte space - clearly overkill for you year needs (a short 2 bytes holds +/- 32k and a byte holds +/- 128)

So using a Text is less efficient by 1 byte when it comes to serializing the data (compared to a IntWritable).

The other thing to consider is how the raw comparators work for each type:

Text.Comparator will skip over the vint bytes denoting the length and then start comparing the characters byte by byte - so you'll need to get to the 5th byte to compare the year 2000 and 2001 (1 byte length + the difference is in the 4th character). But if the difference is in the first character (say between 1999 and 2000) then the raw comparator has an answer after the 2nd byte.

A IntWritable.Comparator reads in the 4 bytes for each key and then does a int comparison so no matter if you're comparing the number 123456789 and 1, it will have to process all 4 bytes from each key before it can do the comparison.

So in summary, Text is more expensive to serialize but cheaper to compare.

You do have another option depending on your data domain - if for example you only have to represent the years from say 1970, then you can use a ByteWritable to denote the year after 1970 (allowing you to represent the years 1970 - 2097), and will only cost a single byte to serialize and single byte when comparing.

If you need to represent a larger range, you could also use VIntWritable which will be more efficient than VIntWritable (probably only requiring 2 bytes to store years in the range 1970-9999).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this great explanation! This really helps and makes me think more on how to use the types based on my needs.

Comment: Oh didn't think of the cheaper comparison! Thanks. And in the last paragraph I believe you have mis-typed VIntWritable twice...

Answer (score 1):

I believe if `IntWritable` does the job for you then you should go with it. `IntWritable` is more lightweight than `Text`.

By this what I mean is that if you see the implementation of both these classes you may see that `IntWritable` has just one property :

```
private int value;
```

While in the implementation of `Text`, you may see that it has 2 properties upfront:

```
private int length;
private byte[] bytes;
```

> Moreover, `Text` class stores text using standard UTF8 encoding. It
>   provides methods to serialize, deserialize, and compare texts at byte
>   level. The type of length is integer and is serialized using
>   zero-compressed format. In addition, it provides methods for string
>   traversal without converting the byte array to a string. Also includes
>   utilities for serializing/deserialing a string, coding/decoding a
>   string, checking if a byte array contains valid UTF8 code, calculating
>   the length of an encoded string.

So, if you do not need all these, why use `Text` class! Go with `IntWritable`.